# Use array value from Python script in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to create a graph from some real data that I have in a CSV file.

I have created a python script that reads my simple Csv file, it has two fields a value and its description.

Now I have been following [this tutorial at around the 11:30 mark](https://youtu.be/02etb849AjQ), they use a Noise Texture node to create a random line.

How do I reference the array in the script instead of the noise texture node, am I correct in thinking I just need to replace the noise texture node with some other node?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Easiest is probably to just make your script create a bezier curve object from the array directly, no need to involve geometry nodes in that if not necessary

Answer (score 0):

As @Duarte Farrajota Ramos suggested, you can just use Python directly to create your line, something like this:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Vector
import bmesh

D = bpy.data

# random array as "data"
nums = np.random.rand(1, 25)[0]

# where the graph line will start and end
start_x = -2
end_x = 2

# number of points along the x axis to divide the segment into
num_x_vals = (end_x - start_x) / (len(nums)+1)

# create an array of vectors with the new vertex locations
x_locs = np.arange(start_x, end_x, num_x_vals)
vectors = [Vector((x, 0.0, z)) for x, z in zip(x_locs, nums)]

# create a new object and bmesh to create verts
mesh = D.meshes.new('graph_line')
obj = D.objects.new('graph_line', mesh)
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)

# create the verts
for vec in vectors:
    bm.verts.new(vec)

# loop over the verts and connect them to create edges  
for i, vert in enumerate(bm.verts[:]):
    try:
        verts = [vert, bm.verts[:][i+1]]
        bm.edges.new(verts)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    
# update and instantiate the mesh in the viewport
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
```